# How to assign label iterating by another colum pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like this:

```
Data | Value |
1.01 |   1   | 
2.01 |   Na  | 
3.01 |   Na  |  
4.01 |   Na  | 
5.01 |   1   | 
6.01 |   Na  | 
7.01 |   Na  | 
8.01 |   1   |
```

I would like to add new column with label, where label change incrementally based on column Value. If there is a changed in column value then ther should be next label.

```
Data | Value | Label
1.01 |   1   |  1
2.01 |   Na  |  2
3.01 |   Na  |  2
4.01 |   Na  |  2
5.01 |   1   |  3
6.01 |   Na  |  4
7.01 |   Na  |  4
8.01 |   1   |  5
```

How to  do it in pandas python avoiding iterating by row?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

IIUC comapre shifted values for not equal with cumulative sum and assign to new column `Label`:

```
df['Label'] = df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum()
```

Comment: looks like many times duplicate ;)